# Why did nkf command remove one character when converting to UTF8 from UTF8-MAC?

Tags: macos, utf-8, iconv

I have a text file encoded with UTF8-MAC.
This contains one line, `Åtvidaberg`.

The nkf command removes one character `"t"` when converting this text file to UTF8 from UTF8-MAC.
What is the reason?

```
$ cat test.txt
Åtvidaberg

(↑ \x41\xCC\x8A\x74\x76\x69\x64\x61\x62\x65\x72\x67)

$ nkf -w --ic=UTF8-MAC test.txt
Åvidaberg

(↑ \xC3\x85\x76\x69\x64\x61\x62\x65\x72\x67,  "t" is missing!)
```

Normally, I assumed that no character is deleted.   [This web converter](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-normalization) or the iconv command of macOS does not remove any character when converting the same string  `Åtvidaberg`.

```
$ iconv -f UTF8-MAC -t UTF8 test.txt
Åtvidaberg

(↑ \xC3\x85\x74\x76\x69\x64\x61\x62\x65\x72\x67)
```

### Environment

I tried on macOS10.14.6 and Ubuntu18.04.

The nkf version is as below. Both of them were installed by using the `brew` and `apt` command.

```
In macOS
$ nkf --version
Network Kanji Filter Version 2.1.5 (2018-12-15) 
Copyright (C) 1987, FUJITSU LTD. (I.Ichikawa).
Copyright (C) 1996-2018, The nkf Project.

In ubuntu
$ nkf --version
Network Kanji Filter Version 2.1.4 (2015-12-12) 
Copyright (C) 1987, FUJITSU LTD. (I.Ichikawa).
Copyright (C) 1996-2015, The nkf Project.
```

Comment: I've reproduced this; my expectation is that there's a bug in nkf, and you should open a defect. It isn't really designed to be a general-purpose converter (like iconv). It focuses on Kanji conversion, and I expect it has a bug in this case. If you look at the test cases, there are no UTF8-MAC to UTF8 (UTF-8N) tests: https://github.com/nurse/nkf/blob/master/nkf_test.pl

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think this is just a bug, too. I'll make a bug report later.